# How to get a number inside a div in order to use it in a php if-statement?

Tags: php

Right now, I do something like this:

```
<h4><?php bbp_topic_reply_count(); ?></h4>
 <?php if ( bbp_get_topic_reply_count() == 1 ) : ?>
  <span><?php _e( 'reply' ); ?></span>
 <?php else : ?>
  <span><?php _e( 'replies' ); ?></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

So if there is only one reply it says: **reply** and if there are more it says **replies**.

Now for the voting part its a little bit more complicated.
The function looks like this: `<?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?>`
and it renders something like this:

```
<div class="thumblock ">
1
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, I need to get that "1" to use it as I did in the if-statement I showed above.

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
<div class="topic-like-count">
 <h4><?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?></h4>
</div>
 <?php preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' ,        wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs() , $n );
echo strip_tags( $n[1] ); ?>
 <span><?php _e( 'likes' ); ?></span>
</div>
```

But the whole `.thumblock` div is output again:

```
<div class="topic-like-count">
<h4>
<div class="thumblock ">

 ...

</h4>

<div class="thumblock ">

...

<span>likes</span>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use JavaScript, PHP is server side scripting ...

Comment: What is wrong with calling the `bbp_topic_reply_count()` function again?

Comment: don't think reply count is the same with like(thumbs up) count.

Comment: I suggest you to store such variables inside `head` tag like: `<meta name="thumblock_num" content="1" />`. It will be simpler to parse in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i think correct, below code should help you :

**Last Edit :** ( thanks to Kaolis )

```
preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
echo strip_tags( $n[1] );
```

Comment: Hey it almost worked, but the "1" is being automatically generated by the function `<?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?>` (they are the number of ratings).

Comment: For some reason it is echoing the whole thing again.

Comment: This is the output: `<div class="thumblock ">
1
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
` Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: This is how this function looks like: `wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs($template_id = 0, $read_only = false, $stars_set = "", $stars_size = 0, $stars_set_ie6 = "", $echo = true);`. So echo parameter can be set to false.